# How to convert curl xml response into array in php?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, curl

I am using curl in my project. When i am sending request, the response is coming in the form of XML as bellow. How can i convert this xml into array to present in the web page.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <OTA_HotelAvailRS Version="1.0">
      <Success Id="140948"/>
       <Properties>
         <Property HotelCityCode="ELS" HotelCode="18918" HotelName="Premier Hotel Regent - Demo">
           <RelativePosition Direction="" Distance="0" DistanceUnitName=""/>
           <EssentialInfo>
           </EssentialInfo>
           <RoomStays>
                <RoomStay>
                     <RatePlans>
                          <RatePlan RatePlanCode="50010"/>
                     </RatePlans>
                     <RoomRates>
                          <RoomRate>
                               <Rates>
                                    <Rate EffectiveDate="2011-10-14" ExpireDate="2011-10-15">
                                         <Base Amount="114.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>

                                         <RateDescription Adults="1" Availability="A" Children="0" RoomNum="1">
                                              Standard
                                         </RateDescription>
                                    </Rate>
                               </Rates>
                          </RoomRate>
                     </RoomRates>
                     <Meals Description="Breakfast Buffet" MealType="Breakfast"/>
                </RoomStay>
           </RoomStays>
           <Promotions/>
           <AdditionalInfo>
                <HotelStarDetail rating="3"/>
                <HotelImages>
                     <HotelImage Type="" URL="http://image1.urlforimages.com/1204258guest.jpg"/>
                </HotelImages>
                <HotelDescription>
                     <LongDescription> description</LongDescription>
                </HotelDescription>
           </AdditionalInfo>
      </Property>          
 </Properties>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why convert it to an array at all? PHP is pretty good with XML. Just load up the XML in [SimpleXML](http://nl2.php.net/simplexml) or a [DOMDocument](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and use it directly.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xml->properties->property['HotelName'];
```

Comment: I have edited above xml code. It contains some big code. Now how can i display all HotelName.

Comment: @Hearaman: I don't see your edited XML code. But you can simply `foreach` over an XML tree suing SimpleXML. See example #4 at http://nl.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Thanks for your tip and suggestion

Comment: To achieve this task with given lines, we should keep that response between $xml=<<< XML and  XML; How to keep my response between them. If i keep my response directly in SimpleXMLElement()  output is not coming.